# XML Publisher Oracle Apps

Tags: oracle

How to add logo/pictures in XML publisher(oracle reports)?

I tried but still not getting the logo in output as PDF or Excel.
Where should I put the logo?

Answer (score 1):

if you are developing an .rtf template, it is as easy as inserting an image in word document file.
if you have put your logo file (.png or .jpg) in your server then follow the below steps:
**Step 1:** In your XML data generate the logo file path.
e.g server_path/logo.jpg

**Step 2:** In RTF template, create a form-field to initialize a XSL variable “logo” using code as

**Step 3:** Insert a dummy image on the RTF. This dummy image should have exact same dimensions as the uploaded image file.

**Step 4:** 5.  Right click on the inserted image -> Format Picture -> Alt Text Tab. Enter code - url:{$logo}